# Deploying VMSS with LB each with their own public ip

Tags: azure

How can I deploy a VMSS on Azure behind a LB where **each** instance in the VMSS has it own **separate** public ip?

I'm currently using the following quickstart template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-ubuntu-autoscale

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, I would associate two networkinterfaces to each VM. One would be associated to one of the public IP address, the other would be associated to the backend address pool of the load balancer.

Hope this helps

Best regards

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, how can this be achieved along with autoscaling in the template?

With azure it seems you have to manually create the public ips, where as on AWS and GCP its just a boolean...

Comment: Hi, I was curious so I tried to build this kind of template for the VMSS. I encountered an issue I would not have met for a VM template.  [ERROR] VM scale set NetworkProfile /subscriptions/xxx/re
16:15:42 - [ERROR] sourceGroups/VMScaleSet/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/ste
16:15:42 - [ERROR] phgouv/updateGroups/dea35259-09c3-437c-a609-21b338569478 must have exactly one 
16:15:42 - [ERROR] NetworkInterfaceConfiguration

Comment: hmm, so a vmss instance can only have one network profile? Are there any alternative methods of doing this?